# SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

When i work on the local server on a visual studio then their is no problem
when i deploy this code and run the online then is face this problem

error on the server after deploying but on a local server there is no problem:

[image: error on the server after deploying but on a local server there is no problem]

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
        int portNumber = 587;
        bool enableSSL = true;

        string emailfrom = "example@gmail.com";
        string password = "*********";
        string subject = "Contact Form Data";
        string emailto = "example@gmail.com";
        string name = n.Value;
        string useremail = em.Value;
        string phone = tel.Value;
        string dept = dep.Value;
        string dest = des.Value;
        string adu = ad.Value;

        
        string body = "Name: " + name + " ;" + " Email: " + useremail + " ;" + "Telephone: " + phone + " ;" + " Departure Place: " + dept + " ;" + "Destination Place: " + dest + " ;" + " Adults: " + adu + " ;" + " ;" + "Children: " + chil +  " ;";

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailfrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailto);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;




            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailfrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try with the `25` port

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution.

1) A low security level doesn't allow you to specify the smtp port. Default is port 25. Although my ISP specifies port 587,Use port 25.

2) Add Code in Web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    .....
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Hope its Work!!

Happy Coding!!

Comment: my web config file is already
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>

Comment: @Shafiq.Rai You may need to contact your hosting provider about the smtp details that you need to use.They block port 25? Please ask them.

Comment: i try to use port 25, 80, 587 
but still i am facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the SMTP port to port 25. I think it should work.

Answer (score -1):

The error is caused by your server's trust configuration. Usually the trust level is sufficient for this library to work but it might be because of special trust configuration on your server or maybe you are deploying on Linux server or something.

Ok it doesn't matter why but you can solve it by manually granting trust to that library by adding this node in your `Web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
        <fullTrustAssemblies>
            <add assemblyName="System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission" version="4.0.0.0" publicKey="b77a5c561934e089"/>
        </fullTrustAssemblies>
    </securityPolicy>
</system.web>
```

Please check the info I used with the error data. If error changed with other assembly name add them as well.

For more information you can see these two resources:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyts434y.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302361.aspx

Comment: This not work in commercial host service, like KingHost.